# Scheduling batch Apex

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

Hi this is my batch apex code

```
global class batchAUpdate_based_on_stage implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,child_stage__c FROM Child__c ';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Child__c> scope)
    {
        for (child__c child : scope){

         if(child.child_stage__c == '25%'){
             child.child_stage__c = '100%';
         }
          update child;

        }
    }  
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
    }
}
```

And this is my scheduler class when i save it i'm not getting in the scheduled job list, i mean at Setup>moniter>scheduled job

```
global class Scheduler_class implements Schedulable{
    global void execute (SchedulableContext SC){
         batchAUpdate_based_on_stage b1 = new  batchAUpdate_based_on_stage();
       database.executeBatch(b1);
      // string sch = '0 0 0 1 4 ?';
       string sch = '0 1 1 * * ?';
       system.schedule ('Batch', sch, new Scheduler_class());
    }
}
```

can anyone tell where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just saving the class does not schedule it.  You still need to tell the DB to schedule it.  I generally write a schedule function within my class so that I can easily call it in one line, that uses my static chron string within the class.  Something like this should work

```
global class Scheduler_class implements Schedulable{

    public static String sched = '0 00 00 * * ?';  //Every Day at Midnight 

    global static String scheduleMe() {
        Scheduler_class SC = new Scheduler_class(); 
        return System.schedule('My batch Job', sched, SC);
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        batchAUpdate_based_on_stage b1 = new batchAUpdate_based_on_stage();
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(b1,50);           
    }
}
```

The you just need to run `Scheduler_class.scheduleMe();` from execute anonymous and it will be scheduled to run at your interval.  This is important as this tells the DB to actually schedule it.

Comment: Thank you :) it's working great and it's very helpful and there was one mistake in 'return System.schedule('My batch Job', Scheduler_class, SC);' and i changed it to "'return System.schedule('My batch Job', sched, SC);'"

Comment: Good catch.  Yes, that was definitely a mistake.  The issues of typing these up in text editors and not compiling them.  :)  Glad it worked for you

Comment: this code works fine can you please elaborate what this last line is doin ?
"ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(b1,50);" 
where and what is the use of passing batchprocessid ?

Comment: @Sharat This allows you to store a reference to the Apex Job ID. Useful to programmatically check the status of the job later on.

Answer (score 9):

The presence of the class alone will not cause it to make its way into any schedules.

I think you need to run [System.schedule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm#:%7E:text=the%20specified%20user.-,schedule(jobName%2C%20cronExpression%2C%20schedulableClass),-Use%20schedule%20with) from execute anonymous (eg in Developer Console).

```
System.schedule('My First Schedule', '0 1 1 * * ?', new Scheduler_class())
```